# Retrieve a specific parent of child button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html structure (very general), the id of the div is added dynamically, by a function that creates sequential objects made this way:

```
 <div id="mydiv1">
     <div> Stuff</div>
     <div>
        <button id="remove"></button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The button "remove" should remove the div where he is, so I have to retrieve the id of the div to do it. I do not know how. How can you make using jQuery? thank you

```
<form>
   <div id="mydiv1">
     <div> Stuff</div>
     <div>
        <button id="remove"></button>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div id="mydiv2">
     <div> Stuff</div>
     <div>
        <button id="remove"></button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I tried:

```
("#remove").click(function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
}
```

But the result is: "remove" instead of "mydiv1" or "mydiv2"

Comment: You are using jQuery btw :)
You should change "How can you make using node js and javascript?" to "How am I able to achieve this using jQuery?" (node.js doesn't make sense in this context).

Comment: The question is not related to `nodejs`

Comment: you are right, correct error :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `class` instead of `id` for the buttons (`id` should be unique):

```js
$('.remove').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('div[id^="mydiv"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="mydiv1">
    <div>Stuff 1</div>
    <div>
      <button class="remove">REMOVE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mydiv2">
    <div>Stuff 2</div>
    <div>
      <button class="remove">REMOVE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

EDIT: Updated to new code posted by OP

Comment: I'm sorry the button is inside another div!

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).parent('div')` to get the first parent node of type `<div>`

```
$("#remove").click(function(event) {
    var parent = $(this).parent('div');
    parent.remove();
}
```

*EDIT*

So add a class to your divs, let say `.divRow` for example

```
<form>
    <div id="mydiv1" class="divRow">
       <div> Stuff</div>
       <div>
           <button id="remove"></button>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mydiv2" class="divRow">
       <div> Stuff</div>
       <div>
           <button id="remove"></button>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and your javascript would be in this case

```
$("#remove").click(function(event) {
    var parent = $(this).parent('.divRow'),
            id = parent.attr("id");
    alert(id);
    parent.remove();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry the button is inside another div!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.remove').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
  //This will give you the id
});
```

For the next part of your question try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.remove',function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
  //This will give you the id
});
```

Comment: this work thanks, but I need to retrieve the id before deleting. :/

Comment: ok understood. Last question: the second div in question is a clone of the first, then when I do the same operation on the second I did not find anything, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For mydiv2 change button like this:

```js
$(".remove").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $("#mydiv"+id).remove();
}
```

```html
<button class="remove" data-id="2"></button>
```